# Link only libc, and not libc++ in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Is it possible, with both `clang` and `gcc`, in a **portable** way to **not** link `libstdc++` or `libc++`, but still link `libc` and use all the features of C++ (well, only classes).

`-nodefaultlibs` doesn't seem to work after my first test (tested on OS X), it does not link `libstdc++`, but it also doesn't link with `libSystem`, which is required.

Comment: Just add the system libraries manually?

Comment: I don't get the motivation. You just want to write C with Classes, so you're running the C++ compiler on C code?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I just want to have C with classes.

Comment: @KerrekSB While that works, it's not portable.

Comment: @KerrekSB After testing to just link libc, it looks like `libc` is called `libSystem` on OS X, and is linked just fine.

Comment: Yes, use `gcc` instead of `g++` when linking. The `gcc` frontend program will not attempt to link with the C++ runtime.

Comment: I have no idea how one can speak about portability when specifying the compiler. Off the top of my head, with gcc, you will have no `new` or `delete`, and without those it's rather difficult to use classes. You will also have to disable exception handling and RTTI.

Comment: @n.m.: `new` or `delete` are unusual in C++ code. You may or may not be using allocators, but you can tell the compiler to use a default allocator that uses `malloc`, not `::operator new`...

Comment: @KerrekSB How do you normally use std::unique_ptr? Can you pass an allocator to std::make_shared? I guess one could implement some equivalent of those with malloc. This is my mistake anyway, as the standard allows one to simply replace new and delete with an altarnative implementation.

Comment: @n.m.: Prefer `allocate_unique` of course, or a vector-of-one :-) I'm being facetious; of course there's a lot of useful C++ you get from using `new` under the hood, but I think there's also a vast amount of useful C++ that *doesn't* need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, and most portable solution is, to just not link any default libraries, and link everything manually.

Adding:

```
-nodefaultlibs -lc
```

will not link anything, and afterwards just link `libc`. Now you've got `C with Classes`.

You can verify that with either `otool -L` (on OS X) or `ldd` (on Linux).
On OSX the output now is:

```
 $ otool -L ./test
   test:
     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

instead of

```
$ otool -L ./test
  ./test:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
```